# Message shown when a user can't chat yet has wrong grammar

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, chat

during the stackexchange downtime, I got he following message, and noticed something weird in it.

[image]

so you need 20 to post messages. **20 WHAT?**

Comment: 20 unicorns of course.

Comment: A necklace with 20 freshly cut ears

Comment: "If M were really sure I was bent, she'd have sent a 00. Your file shows no kills, and it takes..." "Two". (Apparently chatting on SO has somewhat higher requirements than 00-status in MI6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hardest part about this was actually coming up with a good response to your question. I have utterly failed :(

On the bright side, the message is fixed.